# How to pass params through a checkbox tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, parameters, simple-form

I have a simple form with a checkbox.
I'm trying to pass a `sale_id` through the checkbox. However in the controller, the `sale_id` is not in the params hash.

I have tried different (unsuccessful) ways below:

```
<%= ff.check_box :refund, sale_id: sale.id, checked: true %>

<%= ff.check_box :refund, data: {sale_id: sale.id}, checked: true %>
```

Comment: Can you show your terminal logs when you submit this form?

Comment: Why not just call the checkbox different things and not `refund` ? It's just a boolean so make your life easier.

Comment: Can you give this code some context? Its very unclear what you're actually trying to do. Do you have a list of sales and the user is selecting which sales to refund?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass in a single sales ID you can assign arbitrary values to the checked/unchecked states by passing them in as the 3rd and 4th arguments (after the options) e.g.

```
<%= ff.check_box :refund, {}, sale.id, nil %>
```

If it's an array of things to refund, then you can pass in `multiple: true` as an option, e.g.

```
<%= ff.check_box :refund, {multiple: true}, sale.id, nil %>
```

See [the docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) for more info on check_box.

As some of the commenters have noted - it's very unclear why you would want to do this and there may be a better pattern/approach. It'd be helpful if you included what you're trying to do and how you want to use the value in the controller/model.